# Implementing multivalue dict with dict as values in python

Tags: python, dictionary, append, hashtable

I am using the movielens dataset. I want to make a nested hash-table of (movie, rating) as a value for a key (user number).

My code creates empty tables-

```
f = open("/home/goel/rec/data/u1.base",'r')
user = defaultdict(list)
def init_train_data():
  for line in f:
    token = line.split()
    # print token[j]
    user[ (token[0]) ].append( { (token[1]) : (token[2]) } )
```

How do I append those dict values to the user?

Comment: Please delete this question as it has nothing to solve. My testing function was faulty.

Answer (score 1):

```
this should work:
user[token[0]].append({token[1]:token[2]})
```